# Import CSV data to PostgreSQL - Encoding is invalid

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, encoding, number-formatting

I'm trying to import a CSV file to my PostgreSQL (which is set to utf-8 encoding). I'm using Python 2.76 and the Pandas `read_csv` module. I'm using the following libraries to interact with the database - sqlalchemy and psycopg2.

In order to parse the file i've set the following encoding due to the fact that there are German characters in the file as well:

`df = pd.read_csv(full_path, encoding='windows-1252', sep=';', header=0)`

Upon the insert statement to the database I see the following error:

```
csv file not loaded into database: (<class 'sqlalchemy.exc.DataError'>, DataError('(psycopg2.DataError) invalid input syntax for type double precision: "2.670,40"
```

Currently in the database the formatting of integers and float is in the format `XXXX.XX` while in the CSV `X.XXX,XXX` (seems like the German number formatting style).

What is the appropriate way to convert the format in the CSV file to the one in the database? 
It appears that this is conflict causing the error. I've tried several other encodings including `utf-8-sig`, 'utf-8`and`latin-1`, either work. I also had an approach to replace the dots with an empty character and the commas with a dot but this seems backwards and inefficient.

Thanks!

Comment: That looks like a period as a thousands-separator, and a decimal comma.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just run `number_str = number_str.replace('.', '').replace(',','.')`? Which would remove the thousands-separator and replace the decimal comma with a decimal period.

Comment: There's no reason, I thought there would/is a better solution that would be built in to the reading module of pandas_csv that I am missing.